# How to update state with an error message in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, try-catch

Hi I was trying to update state depending on the error message caught. My code is:

```
const [errors,setErrors] = useState("Blah blah");
const verifyIfObject = (object) => {
    try {
        if (object === "object") {
            return true;
        } else {
            const errMsg = `Error: ${object} is not a js object...`;

        throw errMsg;
        }
     } 
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
         setErrors(e);
    }
};
```

When executing the code with error I get the error message in console:

*"Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."*

Please advise how to change the code so that error messages can be stored in state

Comment: Where do you call this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a try/catch block needs to be used in an async function. You may simplify your function like this:

```js
const [errors,setErrors] = useState("Blah blah");

const verifyIfObject = (object) => {
     if (object !== "object") {
       setErrors(`Error: ${object} is not a js object...`);
       return false
     }
     return true
};
```